# Spring boot application.properties conflict when one application deploys another

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have a Spring boot application that monitors and redeploys another Spring boot application. Both applications use a `application.properties` file for configuration, but when the main application redeploys the other one in case of failure, the secondary application doesn't pick up the configuration of its own `application.properties`.

The secondary app has a Spring boot actuator endpoint configured, which isn't activated when redeployed by the main one (due to its own `application.properties` not being picked up, I suppose). These are the lines that should be picked up in order to enable the actuator endpoint:

```
endpoints.metrics.enabled=true
endpoints.metrics.id=metrics
endpoints.metrics.sensitive=false
```

From the main application point of view, this is the command that I execute via java code:
`bash -c 'java -jar full_path_to_the_jar_file' &`
and tried adding `-Dspring.config.location=file:full_path_to_appliction.properties_file` to this command, but didn't make a difference.

This is the java class used to execute the redeployment is this:

```
package com.my.package;

import org.apache.commons.exec.CommandLine;
import org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor;
import org.apache.commons.lang3.Validate;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

import java.io.IOException;

public class ProcessExecutor {

    private static final Logger LOGGER =
            LoggerFactory.getLogger(ProcessExecutor.class);

    private final String command;

    public ProcessExecutor(String command) {
        Validate.notBlank(command);
        this.command = command;
    }

    public void execute() {
        LOGGER.debug("Command that will be executed: {}",
                this.command);
        CommandLine commandLine = CommandLine.parse(this.command);
        DefaultExecutor executor = new DefaultExecutor();
        executor.setExitValue(1);
        try {
            executor.execute(commandLine);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            LOGGER.error("Error restarting the process: {}",
                    e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

When the same command is run on its own it works correctly and loads all the values in the `application.properties` file. What can I do redeploy the jar correctly from the main application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had similar situation (to restart a docker container or to restart a python script).

I was able to run any shell script using `ProcessBuilder`. What I did is to write a shell script with a `cd /path/to/correct/environment/` and actual running of code `java -jar my-client.jar`. Depending on the nature, I choose whether to run it in background or not ([refer to this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3886/difference-between-nohup-disown-and)). Also, I assume you don't want the executor thread to wait until the end of client application so I spawn a new Thread in my example.

Have you tried this?

```
public static class Slave implements Runnable {
  ProcessExecutor pe;
  public void run () {
    try {
      pe._execute();
    } catch (Exception e) { pe.problemCallback(); }
  }
}

public class ProcessExecutor {
    private static final Logger LOGGER =
            LoggerFactory.getLogger(ProcessExecutor.class);

    private final String command;

    public ProcessExecutor(String command) {
        Validate.notBlank(command);
        this.command = command;
    }

    public void execute() {
        LOGGER.debug("Command that will be executed: {}",
                this.command);
        try {
            Slave s = new Slave();
            s.pe = this;
            Thread t = new Thread(s);
            t.start();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            LOGGER.error("Error restarting the process: {}",
                    e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    public void _execute() {
        ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder ("/full/path/to/shell/script.sh");
        try {
            Process p = pb.start();
            p.waitFor();
        } catch (Exception e) {}
    }
    public void problemCallback () {
        // do something with problem.
    }
}
```

In the shell-script, I spawn a java process with a change-dir command:

```
#!/bin/bash
# correct application.properties and jar file should be in
# /path/to/correct/environment/
cd /path/to/correct/environment/
java -jar my-client.jar # put & here if you want a background
# put disown if you don't want this to die with parent
```

Comment: Yes, the `ProcessExecutor` class is being called by another class that owns a `ExecutorService`, which wraps it and calls it by creating/reusing a thread from the pool, so I use a very similar solutions to yours. About the `cd` in the script, I remember having used a solution like this recently, and it seems to be the root cause of the problem. I will give your solution another try, but I've found a solution via calling `setWorkingDirectory(pathOfWorkingDirectory)` on the `DefaultExecutor`. I'll reply to expand on this.

Comment: Tested the solution using a `cd`, and it's working with no issues so far. I'm going to use this solution rather than the `setWorkingDirectory` one, because the latter would require a bit of parsing of the paths etc. on my side. Thanks for your help!