# Trying to run a .bat file in another directory with java

Tags: java, processbuilder

I'm trying to run a batch file with Process Builder
the Batch file is in another directory

```
String filepath = "D:";
        String filename = "hello.bat";
        try {
            ProcessBuilder p = new ProcessBuilder();
            p.directory(new File(filepath));
            p.command("cmd.exe", "/c ", filename);
            Process process = p.start();
            process.waitFor();
            InputStream in = process.getInputStream();
            ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

            int c = -1;
            while((c = in.read()) != -1)
            {
                baos.write(c);
            }

            String response = new String(baos.toByteArray());
            System.out.println("Response From Exe : "+response);
```

No exceptions are thrown, and it seems that it gets stuck at Process process = p.start(); indefinitely.
also, the batch file itself does not get executed
what could possibly be the issue here??
[I've tried Runtime#exec and Desktop#open as well,  to no avail]

Answer (score 0):

The concept will be similar to this: [Spring boot application.properties conflict when one application deploys another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51151874/spring-boot-application-properties-conflict-when-one-application-deploys-another/51155835#51155835)

There I had provided quite a complete set of code.